# how to show only x number of divisions using JavaScript and the for loop

Tags: javascript

I use below script to show dynamic data in a descending order:

```
var main = document.getElementById( 'container' );

[].map.call( main.children, Object ).sort( function ( a, b ) {
    return +b.id.match( /\d+/ ) - +a.id.match( /\d+/ );
}).forEach( function ( elem ) {
    main.appendChild( elem );
    }

});
```

With PHP, it shows the following for instance:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="data-7">data 7</div>
  <div id="data-6">data 6</div>
  <div id="data-5">data 5</div>
  <div id="data-4">data 4</div>
  <div id="data-3">data 3</div>
  <div id="data-2">data 2</div>
  <div id="data-1">data 1</div>
</div>
```

I want to show only 5 divisions inside `<div id="container">` so I tried adding this in the `forEeach` but it didn't work :

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
}
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the first five elements from the array, with [**`.slice`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
[].map.call( main.children, Object ).sort(...).slice(0, 5).forEach(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works. tell me, how can I append ( apply ) the sliced child divisions to another div by ID ?

Comment: `$('#anotherID').append(arrayOfElements)` should just work fine.

Comment: Thanks!! I just wanted to hide other divisions and show only 5, so I ended up using `$('#container div').hide().filter(':lt(5)').show();` and it does the task of hiding other divisions.
Thanks again, and have a nice day !!